# Is there limit of nesting regions and views in Prism?

Tags: prism

From what I understood (I am learning Prism), I can have more
regions in the Shell. Then in a Region in the Shell, I can put a View,
and then in that View I can put more regions. Then in each of those
regions I can put views, and in each view more regions, etc.
I was wondering is there some limit to how many levels I can nest,
or I can go crazy with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question belongs to the family "if you have to ask, you are doing something wrong".
At some point there will obviously be a technical limit to be hit, but it doesn't matter because the design will have crossed into unusable and/or unmaintainable territory long before that happens. For example, Windows apps have a [10K window manager object limit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx) and there are also many [other types of limits](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/02/24/3315174.aspx) imposed on applications but that doesn't matter because no sane application would even come close to reaching them.

So: feel free to make as many regions as you need, but keep in mind that they are the means and not the end.